# Reverse tunnel works manually, not for replication

Tags: mysql, ssh, tunnel

My MASTER mysql server is on a local network, and I have a new slave which is remote (i.e. on the internet). As MASTER does not have an accessible IP, I gathered from the docs that I should establish a reverse tunnel. I execute this:

> ssh -f -N -T -R 7777:localhost:3306 user@slave.slave.com

on the MASTER. The connection seems to work - I can go to the slave and connect
with *mysql* to the MASTER without problem. For some reason though, replication does
not start. MASTER is already replicating to two other slaves without problems - seems the configuration is correct there.

I initiated replication on the slave as:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='127.0.0.1', 
                 MASTER_PORT=7777,
                 MASTER_USER='my_repl', 
                 MASTER_PASSWORD='xxxxx', 
                 MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.nnnnn', 
                 MASTER_LOG_POS=mm;
```

SLAVE STATUS reports mysql trying to connect to the remote, but never succeeding:

```
error connecting to master 'my_repl@127.0.0.1:7777' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400
```

Can anyone suggest how to diagnose this problem?

BTW: OS is Linux.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies... I didn't realize I had to define a new user with 127.0.0.1 as
IP.

So, 'intranet' connections use

```
replication_user@machine_name
```

as id, the connection which comes through the reverse tunnel uses

```
replication_user@127.0.0.1
```

as id. Both have to be declared to mysql separately. The rest of the info in the original message is valid - maybe this helps someone...

Greetings,
John

PS: Forgot to mention - I debugged this remotely (both MASTER and SLAVE are remote to me) using tcpdump:

```
tcpdump -i lo 'tcp port 7777'
```

on the SLAVE side, and

```
tcpdump -i lo 'tcp port 3306'
```

on the MASTER (of course that would not be very useful when there is much traffic).