# How to replicate mysql from src host?

Tags: mysql, backup, replicate

Situation:

MySQL server "Src" is behind a router. So "Src" has no public address.
How could I replicate "Src" to MySQL server "Dst" who has public address.

Maybe there are some agent tools who act as a agent run on "Src" host
will read update from "Src", replicate to "Dst"

Comment: @NZD
Tried SymmetricDS.
It solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by replicate?

Is that [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) or [backup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-and-recovery.html) as defined on the MySQL site?

For a replication scenario, the slave ("Dst") must be able to talk to the master ("Src") to request replication data, which is not possible in your set-up. The MySQL site states:

> Each slave that connects to the master requests a copy of the binary log. That is, it pulls the data from the master, rather than the master pushing the data to the slave.

It could work using a `reverse tunnel`. See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18166143/4459346) for how.

A backup scenario can use `mysqldump` on "Src" to dump the database to a file and then upload or otherwise transfer the file to "Dst". This can be scheduled using a cron job on Linux or 'Task Scheduler' on Windows.

Comment: Yes, That's why I want the agent run in "Src" host.

Comment: @tryer3000 Some questions: (1) Do you need replicate or backup? (2) Are you running Linux or Windows?

Comment: @tryer3000. It could work using a reverse tunnel. See this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18166143/4459346) for how.